# Mention more than one coloumn in where cause

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-like

I want to do search in my app. Here is a general look of my query

```
SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE Col1 OR col or Col3 LIKE "String";
```

My question is what is the correct syntax for that query.
Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Either col1 and/or col2 are boolean columns, then this is fine. Or, you want  "Col1 LIKE "String" OR col LIKE "String" or Col3 LIKE "String"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE Col1 LIKE "%String%" OR col  LIKE "%String%" or Col3 LIKE "%String%";
```

Comment: @Tal there can be every character. Something like `123StringABC` will be mached. Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM My_Table 
WHERE Col1 LIKE '%String%' 
OR Col LIKE '%String%' 
OR Col3 LIKE '%String%';
```

It will search the entry in all the mentioned columns with the wildcard % on the both sides of the needle

Comment: Now you are renaming the column "String". Double quotes are for identifiers, single quotes for character literals in ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM My_Table 
WHERE Col1 LIKE '%String%' 
   OR col  LIKE '%String%' 
   or Col3 LIKE '%String%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as following

```
SELECT * FROM My_Table 
WHERE Col1 LIKE "String" OR 
      Col  LIKE "String" OR 
      Col3 LIKE "String";
```

In place of "String" you can use wildcard characters like % or - .

You can go through [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM My_Table 
WHERE LOWER(Col1) LIKE '%string%' 
OR LOWER(Col2) LIKE '%string%' 
OR LOWER(Col3) LIKE '%string%';
```

It is usually recommended to keep the search non case-sensitive. Here is the syntax for it.